# Validate XML against DTD - expected markup not found

Tags: c#, xmlreader, dtd, xml

I know there are similar questions here on SO. Unfortunately I could not find any that provided an answer for me.
I am trying to validate an XML against an existing DTD file but my code keeps throwing

> expected DTD markup not found. Line 1 Position 1.

This is what the XML looks like (head only, abbreviated):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE tms PUBLIC "-//Schema//DTD DocuMan TMS V5//EN" "Tms.dtd"[]>
<tms name=...
```

This is what the referenced DTD looks like (commented copyright at the beginning, omitted, abbreviated for readibility):

```
<!ENTITY % para 'p|codeblock|procedural-instructions'>
<!ENTITY % list '(ul|ol)'>
...
...
<!-- simple reference to original dtd -->
<!ENTITY % ST4.dtd SYSTEM "ST4.dtd">
%ST4.dtd;
...
...
<!ELEMENT tms (tmsnode|node|rtf)*>
<!ATTLIST tms
...
...
```

The referenced second DTD looks like this:

```
<!ENTITY lt    "&#38;#60;"> <!-- < -->
<!ENTITY gt    "&#38;#62;"> <!-- > -->
<!ENTITY amp   "&#38;#38;"> <!-- & -->
...
...
<!ELEMENT comment (#PCDATA| br | tab)*>
...
...
```

None of the DTDs has an extra "DOCTYPE" element in case you were wondering.

This is my code for reading / validating the XML file against the DTDs:

```
var xml = new XmlDocument();
try
{
    xml.Load(fil);
    var settings = new XmlReaderSettings
    {
        DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Parse,
        ValidationType = ValidationType.DTD,
        XmlResolver = new XmlUrlResolver()
    };
    var context = new XmlParserContext(xml.NameTable,
        new XmlNamespaceManager(xml.NameTable),
        xml.DocumentType.Name, "", xml.DocumentType.PublicId, xml.DocumentType.SystemId, "", "en", XmlSpace.Default);
    using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(fil, settings, context))
    {
        try
        {
            while (reader.Read()){}
        }
        catch (Exception except)
        {
            bkwValidate.ReportProgress(index, Path.GetFileName(fil) + ": " + except.Message);
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception exception)
{
    bkwValidate.ReportProgress(index, Path.GetFileName(fil) + ": " + exception.Message);
}
```

**Update**:

Turns out there was an error in the code I googled up for this: the order of the arguments for the XmlParserContext were incorrect. The empty string for internalSubset needs to come after the sysId. Now this got me one step further:

```
var context = new XmlParserContext(xml.NameTable,
    new XmlNamespaceManager(xml.NameTable),
    xml.DocumentType.Name,xml.DocumentType.PublicId, xml.DocumentType.SystemId, "","", "en", XmlSpace.Default);
```

Unfortunately, I am now stuck with an error

> cannot have multiple DTDs

Comment: I think I may have found something. If I use a different overload for the context, the error changes to "cannot have multiple DTDs", which brought me there: here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22516221/xmlreader-throws-multiple-dtds-error . Will try this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heureka!

The trouble lay with the XmlParserContext: it was simply too detailed!

If I keep it down to the bare necessities, this works just fine, even with multiple DTDs:

```
var xml = new XmlDocument();
try
{
    xml.Load(fil);
    var settings = new XmlReaderSettings
    {
        DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Parse,
        ValidationType = ValidationType.DTD,
        XmlResolver = new XmlUrlResolver(),
        NameTable = xml.NameTable
    };

    var context = new XmlParserContext(xml.NameTable, new XmlNamespaceManager(xml.NameTable), "en",
        XmlSpace.Preserve);

    using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(fil, settings, context))
    {
        try
        {
            while (reader.Read()) { }
        }
        catch (Exception except)
        {
            bkwValidate.ReportProgress(index, Path.GetFileName(fil) + ": " + except.Message);
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception exception)
{
    bkwValidate.ReportProgress(index, Path.GetFileName(fil) + ": " + exception.Message);
}
```